# Force a file to overwrite instead of appending the filename

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, filenames

I've got an application running is OS X that won't overwrite a file with the same filename. It will only append the filename with a 'space 1'. If I write a file more than once I get something like this:

```
* filename.jpg
* filename 1.jpg
* filename 2.jpg
```

What I need is to only ever have the newest file without the extra space and number.

Is there anyway around this? Perhaps an applescript running in the folder?

Comment: Delete the file before running the application ?

Comment: What application? There might be a setting we can suggest if we knew what you were using.

Comment: It's Capture One from Phase one. Part of their design philosophy is to never overwrite files. But in my workflow it would really help to not have these extra files.

Comment: Cross-posted ([tsk, tsk](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata)) to AskDifferent as [#9791](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/force-a-file-to-overwrite-instead-of-appending).